# ¿Como expresar en álgebra relacional los cuantificadores?

Tags: sql

Estoy estudiando la álgebra relacional, pero para mi las cuantificadores plantean algunas dificultades. En efecto en los ejercicios encontrados, no fue capaz expresar al menos, hacer una diferencia con solamente, ∀...

Por ejemplo:

> Tengo tres base de datos `Gusta(Persona, Tema)`, `Estudia(Persona, Tema)`, `Odia(Persona,Tema)`. ¿Cómo expresar en álgebra relacional las personas que gustan **solamente** dos temas?
>
> ...
>
> ¿Cómo expresar en álgebra relacional las personas que odian **todos** los temas que Charles gusta?

...

1. “ρ<sub>Tema2/Tema</sub>(π<sub>Persona=Charles</sub>(Gusta))”  nos da la misma tabla, pero con temas que Charles gusta renombrada a Tema2.
2. hacemos una "unión natural" entre la tabla original y las de las personas que odian: “Odia ⋈ ρ<sub>Tema2/Tema</sub>(π<sub>Persona=Charles</sub>(Gusta))
3. filtramos cuando se trata del mismo tema: “σ<sub>Tema=Tema2</sub>(Gusta ⋈ ρ<sub>Tema2/Tema</sub>(Gusta))”
4. quedan las tuplas con temas equivalente.

πPersona(σ<sub>Tema=Tema2</sub>(Gusta ⋈ ρ<sub>Tema2/Tema</sub>(Gusta)))?

> Con dos base de datos `Préstamo(Persona, Libro, FechaPréstamo, FechaRetornoEsperado, FechaRetornoEfectivo)`, `Retraso(Persona, Libro, FechaPréstamo,Pena)`
>
> ¿Cómo expresar en álgebra relacional las personas que acudiesen **todos** los libros?

... π<sub>Persona</sub>(π<sub>Libro</sub>(Préstamo)?

No estoy seguro de mis intentos...

Por eso, esto me da cuenta que no tengo ninguna problema con la álgebra relacional excepto por los cuantificadores

Entonces, ¿Tiene usted un método?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para el primer caso no hacen falta cuantificadores. Hay un operador que sirve justamente para eso: división (/).

Entonces, si “π<sub>Tema</sub>(σ<sub>Persona=Charles</sub>(Gusta))” son los temas que le gustan a Charles,

> Odia / π<sub>Tema</sub>(σ<sub>Persona=Charles</sub>(Gusta))

nos trae las tuplas deseadas.

Copio la definción del operador de Wikipedia:

> Supongamos que tenemos dos relaciones A(x, y) y B(y) donde el dominio de y en A y B, es el mismo.
>
> El operador división A / B retorna todos los distintos valores de x tales que para todo valor y en B existe una tupla <x,y> en A.

El segundo problema no se entiende. “Acudiesen” no es la traducción correcta de lo que querés decir, porque no tiene sentido en ese contexto.